# Google charts tooltip is not shown on hovering over the data-point but somewhere below it.Why?

Tags: graph, google-visualization

I have a chart which gets updated every second with new data and is plotted as a moving graph.
The issue I face is that,the tooltip does not become visible on hover over the datapoint but some arbitary point below the data point.
[Please Click here to see a snapshot of my graph with tooltip. The black dot refers to my cursor position here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P6YNR.png)

The graph is rendered inside a div.
Has anyone faced this issue before?
I can provide more data if needed.

Edit:It seems when I add a bootstrap class to my div,this behavior becomes visible.If I remove the bootstrap class,it works as expected.I wonder why.